# How can I render specific piece of data from my mongodb into my html?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It's my first project. I'm creating a website where administrator have the privilege to change home page texts. So I'm keeping all texts in a collection called "Texts" , each document has a text:value . When home page is rendered I use `Texts.find()` to return an array containing objects each has a "text" value. I link it to my home page using index.
Like this..
`<h2>Texts[0].text</h2>`, so if i have 100 texts I go all the way to `<h2>Texts[100].text</h2>`. and they are different texts and I need to put them in a specific order so I can't just throw them into my html.
I know that's so stupid , so I'm looking for some idea instead of this. 
--------------Modification------------------>>>>
I tried using find method for arrays but it also is so tiring , so something simpler would be great , here's a portion of the code

```html
 <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img src="<%=imgsArr.find(x => x.name === 'main2').src%>" class="card-img" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay ">

        <h2 class="card-title"><%=textArr.find(x => x.id === 14).text%></h2>
        <div class="triangle-up"></div>
        <hr class="ml-0 ">
        <div class="triangle-down"></div>
        <p class="card-text "><%=textArr.find(x => x.id === 15).text%></p>


          <div class="card-topic">
          <h2 class="card-title" style=";"><%=textArr.find(x => x.id === 16).text%></h2>
          <p class="card-text"><%=textArr.find(x => x.id === 17).text%></p>
          </div>

          <div class="card-topic">
          <h2 class="card-title" style=""><%=textArr.find(x => x.id === 18).text%></h2>
          <p class="card-text"><%=textArr.find(x => x.id === 19).text%></p>
          </div>


          <div class="btnOut ">
          <button  class="btn btn-lg shadow-lg "><a href="/menu">MENU</a></button>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news is that for loops are always a good option. If you are using ejs or a similar rendering engine something like this should work, although you will have to tweak it a bit. Take a look are the EJS rendering engine documentation for an exact format, but it would look something like below and no matter how long the list gets it will render as much as it receives(if it is a lot you might want to consider using pagination)

```
  <% for text in Texts.text %>
   <% if text==="some value"%>
       <h2>text</h2>
   <% else %>
       <p> text </p>
```

If your front-end is perhaps react.js or vue.js or similar the same prnciple would work but the format will be different.

Comment: I edited the head of my question , I don't want to just throw them all into my html, they are different texts in different containers , <h2> , <span> , <p> , so each text record should fall into its place

Comment: I have edited my response to show indicate a way you can accomplish what you have, note it is just to highlight the concept to you, for full understanding refer to the ejs documentation, but this is generally how things work.

Comment: Problem is that texts are retrieved from database , and they can be rewritten by admin so I  can't but an if statement because sooner or later it's going to return false , besides I have over 50 texts a page , does that mean I have to use +50 if statements a page?

Comment: look at my second answer, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

No offense friend but you need to get some tutorials. But let me help you as best i can. Everything in a web application is somewhat defined. Meaning it falls into one predetermined category or another. When you get json for example you get something base on how that particular data is defined in the database. Hence you can get json data from your backend that looks

```
{ 'title':'sneaker', 'price':'200', 'quantity':'50' }
```

Now assuming it is a list of json objects what you can do is loop through this and assign them to tags based on their object key(because it gets converted to a javscript object). so again you code would look something like

```
<% for text in Texts.text %>
       <h2>text.title</h2>
       <div>
         <p>text.price</p>
         <p>text.quantity</p>
       </div>
```

This would be how you would render data from your database(the format might not exactly be spot on). Dealing with forms is a whole other ball game. So get a book or some tutorial videos that discuss it. You will better understand how to handle it.
For your code you are being very rigid, at first glance there is already a pattern, work with that pattern, you code just needs a simple for loop from what i gather.

```
for(let i=0; let i>100; i++){
    if (i%2===0){
       console.log(<h2> i </h2>)
    }else{
       console.log(<p> i </p>
    }
}
```

The reason i have resulted to pure javascript is so you can see what the inner workings of your render should look like. You can get the total number of ids in your database(that is what the integer 100 represents in this case), loop through one by one and produce what you want. It is still javascript, do not let the html throw you off

Comment: Brother , I get that. I know the basics. I edited my question again and added a portion of my code for more clarity

Comment: so does that mean if I have like 50 texts , and they are different with no pattern fits them (so I can't use an if statement to decide which to render), I have to do what I did in my piece of code?

Comment: If you have 50 texts with no patterns at all then you should start afresh with a well defined or a somewhat defined schema with a pattern even if the pattern is not an obvious one or even poorly constructed